# Which function to call? (delegate to a sister class)

Tags: c++

I just read about this in the C++ FAQ Lite

[25.10] What does it mean to "delegate to a sister class" via virtual inheritance?

```
 class Base {
 public:
   virtual void foo() = 0;
   virtual void bar() = 0;
 };

 class Der1 : public virtual Base {
 public:
   virtual void foo();
 };

 void Der1::foo()
 { bar(); }

 class Der2 : public virtual Base {
 public:
   virtual void bar();
 };

 class Join : public Der1, public Der2 {
 public:
   ...
 };

 int main()
 {
   Join* p1 = new Join();
   Der1* p2 = p1;
   Base* p3 = p1;

   p1->foo();
   p2->foo();
   p3->foo();
 }
```

"Believe it or not, when Der1::foo() calls this->bar(), it ends up calling Der2::bar(). Yes, that's right: a class that Der1 knows nothing about will supply the override of a virtual function invoked by Der1::foo(). This "cross delegation" can be a powerful technique for customizing the behavior of polymorphic classes. "

My question is:

1. What is happening behind the scene.
2. If I add a Der3 (virtual inherited from Base), what will happen? (I dont have a compiler here, couldn't test it right now.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is happening behind the scene.

The simple explanation is that, because inheritance from `Base` is virtual in both `Der1` and `Der2`, there is a single instance of the object in the most derived object `Join`. At compile time, and assuming (which is the common case) virtual tables as dispatch mechanism, when compiling `Der1::foo` it will redirect the call to `bar()` through the vtable.

Now the question is how the compiler generates vtables for each of the objects, the vtable for `Base` will contain two null pointers, the vtable for `Der1` will contain `Der1::foo` and a null pointer and the vtable for `Der2` will contain a null pointer and `Der2::bar` [*]

Now, because of virtual inheritance in the previous level, when the compiler processes `Join` it will create a single `Base` object, and thus a single vtable for the `Base` subojbect of `Join`. It effectively merges the vtables of `Der1` and `Der2` and produces a vtable that contains pointers to `Der1::foo` and `Der2::bar`.

So the code in `Der1::foo` will dispatch through `Join`'s vtable to the final overrider, which in this case is in a different branch of the virtual inheritance hierarchy.

If you add a `Der3` class, and that class defines either of the virtual functions, the compiler will not be able to cleanly merge the three vtables and will complain, with some error relating to the ambiguity of the multiply defined method (none of the overriders can be considered to be the *final overrider*). If you add the same method to `Join`, then the ambiguity will no longer be a problem, as the final overrider will be the member function defined in `Join`, so the compiler is able to generate the virtual table.

[*] Most compilers will not write null pointers here, but rather a pointer to a generic function that will print an error message and `terminate` the application, allowing for better diagnostics than a plain segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `Der3` what will happen depends on which class it inherits from.

As you know, instantiating a class is only possible when all virtual functions have been defined; otherwise you can only make pointers to them. This is to prevent constructing partially defined objects.

In your example you cannot instantiate `Der1` nor `Der2` directly because in `Der1`, `bar()` is still pure virtual and in `Der2`, `foo()` is pure virtual.

Your `Join` class can be instantiated because it inherits from both and has therefore no pure virtual function.

Once you have made an instance of a class, you can instantiate pointers to non-instantiable classes by dynamic_casting.

From the moment a class has been instantiated, the virtual function mechanism, that works with a table of pointer to functions, will still call the functions that have been defined at instantiation time.

So the key here is that when you create your object, you create an instance of `Join`. Its virtual functions are defined because you are able to create the object. From that moment, you can call the virtual functions with any pointer to a base class.

Comment: say, it is similar as Der1 and Der2, inherited from Base

Comment: @Johnyy: I tried to expand, but it might be reworked a bit. I am not very good at English to explain technical stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I see why this is interesting to explore. In real code this would probably be hardly useful however. As others pointed out, virtual inheritance is more of a *fix-this-bad-design-to-work-somehow* tool, than a valid desing tool.

Your code produces warnings in VS2010 - the compiler is making you know that dominance is being used. Of course thats not a show stopper, but another discouragement to use this.

If you introduce Der3 like this

```
class Der3 : public virtual Base {
public:
    void bar() {}
};

class Join : public Der1, public Der2, public Der3 {}
```

the code fails to compile because of `ambiguous inheritance of 'void Base::bar(void)'`

Answer (score 0):

One point is missing in the discussion ( none-the-less this is quite informative and thanks to all ).
When you 'virtually inherit' a class. What happens is: a pointer to the virtual base class is kept by most of the compilers ( it can be implemented in different ways by different compilers). So if you take the size of Der1 and Der2, it would be atleast 4 bytes on 32 bit and 8 bytes on 64 bit. Because they have a pointer to the virtual base class and therefore, no ambiguity. That is why when you create the object of Join, it first calls the constructor of Virtual Base class ( not really the first call, but it initializes the pointer which came to it through Der1 and Der2 first in its construtor ). In Join compiler can check the pointer name / type and then it makes sure that only one pointer of virtual base class comes to it from Der1 and Der2. You can check even this by sizeof operator. As we know that compiler puts the calls in the constructor silently. Therefore, it first calls the Virtual Base class's constructor in Depth First way. ( can be checked using all the base classes as virtual derivation ). Rest is already explained

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty stupid example imo and a perfect example of academics making themselves look clever. If this situation ever came up, it would almost CERTAINLY be because of a bug, specifically forgetting to make Der1::foo() virtual.

*Edit*:

I misread the class definitions. Which is exactly the problem with this type of design. It takes a lot of thought to determine exactly what would happen in each of these cases, which is bad. Making your code readable is by far better than being "clever" like this.

Comment: Can you give a pretty smart example to enlighten us?

Comment: wait. Der1::foo() is virtual isn't it?

Comment: Using virtual inheritance at all is often a sign of a spewy design.

Comment: Aside from the bad presentation.... I am trying to understand what happens. Will you share some insight thought on that?

Comment: Maybe the questioner is only academically curious, and doesn't care about real world usage. The questions in and of itself is perfectly valid, no reason to belittle his question.